# Pass function A as prop and call another function when child calls A

Tags: javascript, reactjs

first of all, sorry for the bad title. I was not able to formulate a proper one related to my problem.

I have a little question related to the react code.
My Child component gets passed the onValueChanged function as prop. This function has been given to the parent by the parent of the parent as prop.
How can my specialFunction be called when the Child triggers the onValueChanged function.

(!) I cant extend the onClick call in the Child which triggers the onValueChanged function. The Child-Code can not be changed.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  specialFunction(){
    /* do something */
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child onValueChanged={this.props.onValueChanged} />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Button onClick={this.prop.onValueChanged} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert another function and pass that down (which then triggers your instance method):

```
 <Child onValueChanged={(...args) => {
    this.specialFunction();
    this.props.onValueChanged(...args);
 }} />
```